# How do you get the number

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, seasonal

How do you use the format 1_*_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ to get 222,222,222 using only the numbers 1-9 only once

Comment: Even though the question is simple, it presents an elegant answer. Welcome to Puzzling ! (Don't forget to take our [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour))

Comment: Could have delayed until 22:22 UTC for maximum seasonality points :-)

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is

> 1**8** * **12,345,679** = 222,222,222